# How do I add spaces in async function discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**I am trying to create a discord bot using discord.py and I have come across the following error:
When I try to use spaces in async functions like shown below:**

```
@client.command()
async def helpcmd ping(ctx):
  embed=discord.Embed(title='"ping" Command help', description='See the bot latency in milliseconds', color=0x0000ff)
  embed.add_field(name='Command Aliases', value='[no command aliases]', inline=False)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

**I keep getting a syntax error because of the space in between "helpcmd" and "ping".
Could anyone please help me with this issue? Thanks.**

Comment: You can't use spaces in function names. You can replace by `_`, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitespace is not allowed for variables, classes, functions, etc in practically every programming language.
Discord doesn't parse commands with spaces either. You should use `_` for these purposes instead.

You can also use a single command with an argument

```py
@commands.command()
async def helpcmd(ctx, arg):
    if arg == "ping":
        # do stuff
```

OR, you can make a subcommand.

```py
@commands.group()
async def helpcmd(ctx):
    # do stuff

@helpcmd.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use spaces if functions names try using _ or putting the two words together